# Перенаправляющий поиск по сайту

Tags: javascript, html

Есть поиск по сайту, но я хочу чтобы написанный запрос в поиске был перенаправлен на определенный сайт.

Код, который нужно изменить:

```
<form class="poick_os" onsubmit="document.getElementById('sfSbm').disabled=true" method="get" action="/search/" >
    <input class="poick_pole" type="text" name="q" maxlength="30" value="Поиск..." onclick="if (this.value=='Поиск...'){this.value='';}" />
    <input class="poick_knopka" type="submit" value="Найти" />
    <input type="hidden" name="t" value="0" />
</form>
```

А ещё сложнее - когда пользователь пишет запрос в поиск и нажимает отправить, будет вылезать окно, где его спрашивают, какой из 5 сайтов выбрать, чтобы найти то, что он запросил.

Comment: Я рад за ваше "хочу" и очень не рад за inline JS, но в чём вопрос-то?

Comment: Сорри. Например. Юзер пишет запрос у меня на сайте в поиске "Супермен" и вместо чтобы ему показывали результаты моего сайта, его перекидывало на сайт https://www.vsemayki.ru/search/Супермен

Comment: Суть вашей идеи мне понятна, но с чем у вас возникла проблема при реализации идеи?

Comment: Не понимаю как сделать) Нужен пример

Comment: Я примерно знаю как надо в action="/search/" вставить нужный сайт, но не понимаю откуда идет приписка после /search/ знака "?"

Comment: так про get и post уже понял) Вообщем нужно чтобы переходило на другой сайт с поисковым запросом, а в конце еще приписывалась реф ссылка

Comment: Смена `action` - это, конечно, хорошо и понятно, но, допустим, и на _Google_, и на _Yandex_ вот так просто не обратиться, потому что у них подобные запросы с другого домена запрещены в `X-Frame-Options`.

Answer (score 1):

Если открывать результаты поиска в отдельной вкладке, то можно провернуть что-то вроде такого, меняя `action` формы и `name` у `<input>` в зависимости от выбранной поисковой системы:

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('#searcher').on("change", function() {
        var $selected = $(this).find(':selected');
        $('#search').attr('action', $selected.data('domain'));
        $('#searchValue').attr('name', $selected.data('query'));
    }).change();
});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="search" action="http://google.com/search" target="_blank">
    <input id="searchValue" name="q" maxlength="30" placeholder="Поиск..." />
    <input type="submit" value="Найти" />
</form>
<select id="searcher">
    <option data-domain="https://www.google.ru/webhp" data-query="q">Google</option>
    <option data-domain="https://yandex.ru/search/" data-query="text">Yandex</option>
    <option data-domain="https://www.bing.com/search" data-query="q">Bing</option>
</select>
```

[Полный пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9L5kx72p/1/).

В случае с *Google* результаты поиска не отображаются сразу из-за недостающего в запросе параметра `#newwindow=1`, но суть идеи от этого не меняется.

Comment: @dilux на здоровье. Если ответ вас устраивает, вы можете отметить его как принятый, нажав на галочку в левой верхней части ответа. Надеюсь, это возможно сделать и в закрытом вопросе.